# Forcing an anchor href to treat octet-stream as images?

Tags: html, image, mime-types

I have some images that were incorrectly stored on S3 with the MIME type of `application/octet-stream`. When I put this images on a website with an anchor, ie, `<a href="imgurl"`, the image is automatically downloaded instead of being viewed in the browser.

Is there anyway to workaround this issue and force the browser to treat a link as an image?

Comment: Can you fix the way the files are stored?  If not, I suggest proxying the requests.

Comment: @Brad, Yeah ultimately I think correcting the file storage is the to handle this, but I was wondering if there was a workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why MightyPork deleted his answer, but the basic idea was to create a proxy in PHP which will serve the files with the correct MIME types for you.

```
<?php

function error403() {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  die('You are not allowed to access this file.');     
}

function serveFile($file, $mimeType) {
  header('Content-Type: ', $mimeType);
  header('Content-Length: ', filesize($file));

  readfile($file);
}

function determineMimeType($file) {
  $mimeMap = array(
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'gif' => 'image/gif'
  );
  $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if (isset($mimeMap[$fileExt])) {
    return $mimeMap[$fileExt];
  }
  return false;
}

// entry point
$whitelist = array('test1.png', 'test2.png');
$filePath = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : error403();

if (!in_array($filePath, $whitelist)) {
  error403();
}

$mime = determineMimeType($filePath);
if ($mime === false) {
  // error handling, logging, etc.
}
serveFile($filePath, $mime);
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I am using Grails instead of PHP but I think I might be able to get something to work like the above code.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon That should be feasible. Two important security aspects though: create a whitelist (of files and/or directories) and pay attention to possible `..` in the file path.

Comment: I am going to assume that there means there is no pure client side workaround and mark this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesMcMahon You could also fetch the data via JavaScript/AJAX, but then you have so send special headers when serving the files (=creating a proxy again).